# Analytic function for which $\overline{f(z)} \neq f(\overline{z})$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers

Since $\overline{f(z)} = f(\overline{z})$, where $\overline{z}$ denotes the complex conjugate of $z$, already works for polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$, the exponential function, etc., for which ***analytic*** functions which map $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't it work?

Can you give me a (counter)example. Thanks!

PS: conjugation is a field automorphism in $\mathbb{C}$ which fixes $\mathbb{R}$, so ***if*** anything goes wrong it has to have something to do with the *infinite* summation.

Comment: Not only is conjugation a field automorphism, it is an isometric homeomorphism, so I doubt that infinite summation is going to make anything go wrong either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true of analytic functions that have a real Taylor series (See [Schwarz reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle)): a function defined on a piece of the closed upper half-plane with real values for real $z$ (and hence real Taylor coefficients) extends to an analytic function on the corresponding reflected piece of the lower half-plane by defining $f(\bar{z}) = \overline{f(z)}$. Since analytic continuation is unique, this is always true for functions defined on both domains in the first place.